# Thread.start() - Cannot resolve symbol error in a java class that I want to use to run a background thread reading a hardware device

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Still new to android and java so please be kind,  I do a lot of research BEFORE I ask the question here.

This code works fine in a fragment (at this point I do not want to know about potential problems the code may cause, those will be dealt with as I go along and learn more about android)

```
package com.sample.ui.dashboard;

import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ExecThread(String id) {
  String RequestA = a_string;
  TextView te; //(TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.meternumber);

  Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    String read = null;
    int count = 5;
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
      try {
        while(count != 0)
        {
          Socket socket = new Socket(ipAddress, port);
          socket.setKeepAlive(true);
          OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
          PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out, true);
          output.println(RequestA);
          BufferedReader input;
          input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
          read = input.readLine();

          if (read != null && read.length() >= 250)
          {
            te.setText( String.valueOf(count) + " - " + (CharSequence) read.substring(4, 16));
          }
          socket.close();
          count--;
        }
      }
      catch (IOException e)
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  };
  Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
  
  thread.start();   <<---------------   cannot resolve symbol 'start'
}
```

In the onClick() of a button, the code works fine, this is testing the reading of a device using a modified modbus protocol, since the polling of the device is intended to be a 24 hour operation it cannot be done in the main UI as it will involve extracting a large number of data values and Database activity to Sqlite

My question is, what am I missing in relation to

1. cannot resolve symbol 'start'
2. How can I call the class from the button click in my fragment.

Hope this makes sense

Thanks in advance...

Comment: The line `thread.start()` is not inside a method body.

Answer (score 0):

I have my thread running, thanks to @tgdavies pointing out my omission.

Java class implementation of thread object.

```
  public class myThread
  {
  public void ExecThread(String requestA, String requestB, TextView tv ) {
    TextView te = tv;

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
      String read = null;
      int count = 5;
      @Override
      public void run()
      {
        try {
          while(count != 0)
          {
            Socket socket = new Socket(ip, port);
            socket.setKeepAlive(true);
            OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out, true);
            output.println(requestA);
            BufferedReader input;
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            read = input.readLine();

            if (read != null && read.length() >= 250)
              {
              te.setText( String.valueOf(count) + " - " + (CharSequence) read.substring(4, 16));
              }
            socket.close();
            count--;
          }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    };
    Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
      thread.start();
  }
```

From my fragment onViewCreated( ... )

```
   public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstantState)
    {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstantState);
    myThread h = new myThread();
    binding.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v )
      {
      TextView te = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.mNumber);
      h.ExecThread(r1, r2, te);
      }
    });
```

At this point, I would be happy to take advice on problems that more experienced android developers can see I have no doubt that this can be done better any feedback would be appreciated.